# Prove that $\sec^2x$ is $C^{\infty} $on $(-\pi /2, \pi /2) $?

Tags: real-analysis

> How can I prove that $\sec^2x$ is a $C^{\infty} $  map on $(-\pi /2, \pi /2) $?

If I just try repeated differentiation the expression get complicated.  So how can I see that every derivative will be continuous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the facts that $x \mapsto \cos x$ is smooth on $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, that $x \mapsto x^2$ is smooth everywhere, and that $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is smooth on $(0,\infty)$. Moreover, the composite of smooth functions is smooth.

Comment: I want to show that it is $C^{\infty} $

Comment: @Alexander: This method does that.

Comment: OK understand now, thanks!